# Segfault when trying to access first character of std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, segmentation-fault, stdstring

Consider this piece of code:

```
std::string* symbol = (std::string*) to_push->value;
printf("Got symbol\t%s\n", symbol->c_str());
switch ((symbol->operator[](0)) {
```

Here, `to_push` is a pointer to an object which has an attribute `value` of type `void*`. So i convert that value to `std::string*` because I need to know what is its content.

On the second line, added to get an idea of where the segfault happens, I also try printing the value of that string, which always works.

On the last line though, when I finally try comparing that string's first character over a list of possibilities, I get a segmentation fault error. You see here I'm trying to access the string through the operator `[0]` whitout deferencing it. I've also tried many other combinations, like `*(symbol->c_str())` or `(*symbol)[0]`, but I always get that segmentation fault error.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

If it can be helpful, both the objects pointed to by `to_push` and `to_push->value` are dinamycally allocated.

Comment: Can you add a [MCVE] in your question that reproduces the problem please.

Comment: The last line won't compile. Post real code.

Comment: I'm sure C++11 (since that is one of your tags) has facilities to not have to write code like this, where you're passing around void pointers and hoping it's a `std::string`.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that. I am in a hurry and from mobile. Will fix that asap.

Comment: `switch ((symbol->operator[](0)) {` **Really??**

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie good luck with programming in C++ thinking that you can use an object's method without that object being of a specific, known type. I voted to close my question as "unclear what you're asking", going to find out myself what's the problem, thanks.

Comment: Templates, type-traits, etc. makes using `void *` passing basically obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just convert arbitrary void pointers to strings or any other type for that matter.

This C style cast will *only* work if `value` is actually a pointer to a std::string hiding behind a void pointer.

Comment: That exactly what's happening. Note how I said that the second line prints perfectly.